# Using devise for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The question may not be that complicated, but i am confuse. I have two users i.e. Student and Teacher, and for those i want separate models, controllers and views. I want teacher to use `/t/sign_up` and for student `/s/sign_up`. I am using devise for authentication, I know it is possible because that's how active admin works.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Provided you have already generated multiple models and views with devise, and just want to change the path name, you can do that configuring config/routes.rb:

```
devise_for :students, path: 's'
devise_for :teachers, path: 't'
```

which will replace your routes like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/s/sign_up
http://localhost:3000/t/sign_up
```

If you want to have your views based on different models, you can configure `config.scoped_views = true`  inside `config/initializers/devise.rb` file and generate views for that model:

`rails g devise:views students`

And if you want to customize each controller, you can generate their controller files like this:

`rails generate devise:controllers students`

This will create controllers based on model name, thus you can define them in your routes:

`devise_for :students, path: 's', controllers: { sessions: "students/sessions" }`

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried this and it give me two kind of routes `/s/sign_up` refers to `devise/registrations#new` and second `/t/sign_up` also refers to `devise/registrations#new`. Won't it will create conflicts? How devise will know to create new `student` at `/s/` and a new teacher instance at `/t/`?

Comment: It is easy, if you need different controller behaviour, you can create controllers specifically for that model. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have generated separate controllers for students and teachers in their won directories i.e. `controllers/student/devise` and `controllers/teacher/devise` also configure the routes and `initializers` for devise and generated views. Now devise is using my controllers but still not using my views generated by devise i.e. `rails g devise:views student/devise` and `rails g devise:views teacher/devise`.

Comment: My bad it was just a typo, will accept answer in just a moment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pyfl88,
I tried your solution, seems like I am missing out on something, I am getting following error: ``You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created``
What am I doing wrong?
I need to have two devise models: 1. users 2. registration.

Comment: Has anyone experienced this double model behaviour but where one is managed in a namespace. For exemple something like http://localhost:3000/backend/teachers/sign_up